# Toolbar appears on the bottom instead of top in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using a toolbar for my android app and disabled action bar . For main activity the toolbar comes correctly on the top but for app settings (which is a fragment) it appears on the bottom , any help on this

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.example.app.Settings$NewsPreferenceFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    tools:context="com.example.app.Settings">
<include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: You are using Relative Layout. Right?

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: set toolbar property to alaignparentTop = true

Comment: I did alignParentTop it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using Linear Layout with gravity="bottom" or relativeLayout

Make sure the code resides something like this

The layout should ideally look like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    orientation="vertical">

<include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment     
    android:name="com.example.app.Settings$NewsPreferenceFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.app.Settings">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I use this I am getting error Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id for com.example.app.Settings$NewsPreferenceFragment

Comment: I solved this, I just needed to add a 'id' to the fragment and it worked

Comment: I used the linear layout as you suggested and added 'id' attribute to it. Thanks @Viswanath Kumar Sandu

Comment: add id="@+id/fragment" inside fragment element. It is mandatory to have an id for fragment view

Comment: If you feel the answer is approriate to the question, please mark it as correct. Tahnks